# ListView inside ScrollView, bad idea? Than how to substitute a dynamically populated list inside a ScrollView?

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, scroll, android-scrollview

I am having this issue, where I need to output a "list" dynamically, in one of my activities where a ScrollView is the root element.

I have found a lot of posts where people show workarounds and hacks, but most of them say it is a bad habit placing a listview inside a scrollview. I understand, but none of them show which is the right way? I can think of creating textviews dynamically and adding them to the layout but I am not sure if it would be the best way.

So, how to get this done right?
Thanks!

Comment: Why dont you keep ListView itself as your Root element. Btw ListView is obsolete now. Try out RecyclerView.

Comment: While I disagree on the "obsolete now" point from the previous comment, I do agree with the question about your root element. Since `ListView` can have rows of varying types, and therefore can hold anything you want, why do you think that having a `ScrollView` root is the correct choice?

Comment: @CommonsWare - I have a layout with a lot of child elements (where a scroll view is essential), and the hosting activity has two JSON arrays which I need to loop thought to obtain fresh data. The length of the arrays may vary so a listview was the ideal choice for me. So what else could I implement to display both the JSON arrays, inside a huge layout?

Comment: "I have a layout with a lot of child elements (where a scroll view is essential)" -- a **vertically-scrolling container** is essential. So, I will ask again: why do you think that having a `ScrollView` root is the correct choice for that container, as opposed to a `ListView`?

Comment: @CommonsWare - Is there another way to obtain a "vertically-scrolling container" other then implementing the scrollview as the root element?

Comment: You can use a `ListView`. As I wrote in my first comment, a `ListView` can have rows of varying types, and therefore can hold anything you want. Whatever you wanted in your `ScrollView` can be rows in a `ListView`. There are other vertically-scrolling containers (an appropriately-configured `RecyclerView`, for example, as well as `GridView` and `ExpandableListView`) that you could consider. You might look at [my `MergeAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) for ideas.

Comment: @CommonsWare - thanks for your suggestions, I will take your advice and look for ways to get out the most of a ListView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I did not get the answer I was hoping for. I kept on searching and I found a nice solution which in my situation suits quite well!

I have created a simple LinearLayout and connected my ArrayAdapter to it, while deleting the ListView I was using before. It is not recommended for long lists, but mine is less then 10 items long.

```
...

        //Creating a custom ArrayAdapter
        ArrayAdapter adapt2 = new DirectionsListAdapter(this, myList);      

        //Pointing to the LinearLayout
        LinearLayout testContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.testContainer);
        final int adapterCount = adapt2.getCount();

        //adding each adapter item to the LinearLayout
        for (int i = 0; i < adapterCount; i++) {
              View item = adapt2.getView(i, null, null);
              testContainer.addView(item);
            }

...
```

So far it works really well, I have all the customisation options I had before, it is fast and clean and the best about it is that it adjust its height automatically even inside the root ScrollView.